# Session wont save any variables

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my login the login works it checks the html forms and it the info is correct it will login me to the logged in page.I set the username and user id on the login page after the info is checked but the server seems like it wont save the info. Strange thing is if i logout then use the login the site works registers the username etc  on the login i check the info then set the username into a variable then do

```
if(empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo "Somthing went wrong";
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=logout.php">';  
}
```

But this does not trigger again once i go to the site for the first time in a while i need to view the logout page before i can logout even tho im not logged in of course the logout only destroys the session.

```
if (isset($_POST["Username"]) && !empty($_POST["Username"])) {                       

    $salt= "";

    $username23 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
    $thereusername = strip_tags($username23);

    $password2= sha1 ($salt.$_POST["password"]);

    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
    $statement->execute(array($thereusername,$password2));
    $count = $statement->rowCount();

    /// If usernam and password match we carry on
    if ($count == "1"){

        $username23 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
        $thereusername = strip_tags($username23);

        $statement8 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?  ");
        $statement8->execute(array($thereusername));
        $count8 = $statement8->fetch();

        $username233 = mysql_real_escape_string($count8['id']);
        $_SESSION['userid'] = strip_tags($username233);



        $_SESSION['username'] = $thereusername ; 



        if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){

            echo "Somthing went wrong";
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=logout.php">';  
        }

         if(empty($_SESSION['userid']))
        {
            echo "Somthing went wrong";
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=logout.php">';  
        }

        echo "You are now being logged in";

        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=dashboard.php">';    
        exit;

        echo "works"; 

    }   
};
?>
```

.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Artisanal kale"  name= "Username" id="Username"> 
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
           <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
           <input type="password" class="form-control"  name= "password" id="password"placeholder="Password"> 
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <p>       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn theme-btn"> </p>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

I of course use the session start at the top of the page after i login it takes me to the logged in page but will not display the username or any info ive done print_r session and get Array ( ) i then go to logout.php and login and all works perfect server error or php error ?

Comment: 1. Don't mix `mysql` and PDO. 2. Don't write your own password hashing logic, use `password_hash()` instead. 3. Start your script with `session_start()`.

Comment: session_start() is at top of page :) was always told to add it to the top before everything

Comment: i find it strange that i logout / destory the session and all works fine

Comment: See point 1. You are effectively nulling your username and id unless you open a `mysql` connection as well...

Comment: Im sorry ive got <?php include 'functions/functions.php';$db = mysqlconnect();?> at top to which has the mysql connect and pdo connect

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't do your own password salt/encrypt, you need to use `password_hash()` to save password hashes and `password_verify()` (or bcrypt equivalent) to check the hashed password vs submitted password. Second, as noted, you need to use PDO exclusively. Lastly, you need to make some classes to make your script more manageable and easier to troubleshoot. This is more complex because there are a lot of parts that need to be implemented but this is an basic example of where you should be going with your login and such. I would advise, if you don't understand the majority of this, you probably should download a framework because this type of thing is complex to do it right. Frameworks have this all built in, you just have to program the very top level of the script, for the most part...

**/core/classes/App.php**

```
class App
    {
        # Storage of global arrays
        protected static $GlobalArray = array();
        # Returns post trimmed POST array
        public function getPost($key=false)
            {
                if(!isset(self::$GlobalArray['_POST']))
                    self::$GlobalArray['_POST'] = $this->sanitizeArray($_POST);

                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset(self::$GlobalArray['_POST'][$key]))? self::$GlobalArray['_POST'][$key] : false;

                return self::$GlobalArray['_POST'];
            }
        # Trims the values
        public function sanitizeArray($array)
            {
                if(!is_array($array))
                    return trim($array);

                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $array[$key] = $this->sanitizeArray($value);
                }

                return $array;
            }
    }
```

**/core/classes/User.php**

```
class User extends App
    {
        private $con;
        public function __construct(\PDO $con)
            {
                $this->con = $con;
            }

        public function savePassword($username,$password)
            {
                # Create the password hash
                $hash = password_hash($password);
                # Prepare the query and store password hash
                $query = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE users SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
                $query->execute(array($username,$password));

                return $this;
            }

        public function validateUser($username,$password)
            {
                # Prepare the query to get the user
                $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
                $query->execute(array($username));
                # Assign password
                $user = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if(empty($user['password']))
                    return false;
                # Match hash to password
                if(!password_verify($password,$user['password']))
                    return false;
                # Return the user data
                return $user;
            }
    }
```

**/core/classes/Session.php**

```
class Session extends App
    {
        public function toSession($array)
            {
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        # Save to errors array
        public function toError($array)
            {
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $_SESSION['errors'][$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        # Get error
        public function getError($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_SESSION['errors'][$key]))? $_SESSION['errors'][$key] : false;

                return (isset($_SESSION['error']))? $_SESSION['error'] : false;
            }
        # Get value
        public function get($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_SESSION[$key]))? $_SESSION[$key] : false;

                return (isset($_SESSION))? $_SESSION : false;
            }

        public function start()
            {
                session_start();
            }

        public function destroy($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key)) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
                        $_SESSION[$key] = null;
                        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    session_destroy();
                }
            }
    }
```

**/config.php**

```
# Create important defines
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('CORE',ROOT_DIR.DS.'core');
define('CLASSES',CORE.DS.'classes');
define('FUNCTIONS',ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions');
# A class autoloader is a must...
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $path = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,CLASSES.DS.str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php');
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
# Include connection
include(FUNCTIONS.DS.'functions.php');
# Create connection
$db = mysqlconnect();
# Start the session
$Session = new Session();
$Session->start();
```

**/login.php**

```
# Add our config file
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Create application
$App = new User($db);
# Check if submission login
if(!empty($App->getPost("Username"))) {
    # Get the user array (returns on validated)
    $User = $App->validateUser($App->getPost("Username"),$App->getPost("password"));
    # If user is valid
    if($User){
        $Session->toSession(array(
            'userid'=>$User['id'],
            'username'=>$User['username']
        ));
        # Redirect & stop
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
        exit;
    }
    else {
        # Store the error
        $Session->toError(array("invalid_login"=>"Invalid username or password"));
        # Redirect to error or whatever...
    }
}
```

I haven't really checked this, but I have noted so you know what does what (or is supposed to do). You want to always include the `config.php` at the top of every top level page for consistency.

Use `print_r($Session->get());` to see the session array. Also note the password check won't work if you haven't saved the password hash properly.